# Mysql Inner Join Group By Tutorial Question

Tags: mysql

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-inner-join/#2
Hi folks!
I wonder why after I delete the `GROUP BY orderNumber` then it fetches only one row:

[image]

Is it their "tutorial" database mistake or is it a correct MySQL behavior? If it's correct, then why does it produces this exactly result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL ["aggregate functions"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) including `SUM(), COUNT(), MIN(), MAX()` among others require a frame to aggregate over. Typically that is one or more other columns to apply the `SUM()` or other aggregate onto, and `GROUP BY` is how you specify that frame.

An aggregate query with no `GROUP BY` implies you are taking the `SUM()` of *all* rows matched by the query's `WHERE` clause filter.

MySQL is unlike most other RDBMS in that it *allows* you to remove the `GROUP BY` with unaggregated columns in `SELECT` and still get some rowset back from your query. In Oracle, MS SQL Server, or Postgresql, the query without the `GROUP BY` would be a syntax error. They would also treat it as an error if you used `GROUP BY orderNumber` while still including `status` in the `SELECT` list. A `GROUP BY` should include *every* column which is in the `SELECT` list that isn't being used in the aggregate `SUM(), COUNT(), MIN(), MAX()`, etc.

But MySQL is lenient about its presence and instead tries to guess over which frame to apply your `SUM()` aggregate. Some of the time it can get the answer you were actually expecting, but most other times the values it gives you for the non-aggregated columns are essentially indeterminate. It will collapse several possible values down to just one, and you have no way to pick *which* one you get.

That is the query result you are seeing. MySQL chose `orderNumber = 10100` and `status = 'Shipped'` to go with your `SUM()` even though they are not specifically related to that sum. The sum in your result `9604190.61` is the sum of `quantityOrdered * priceEach` for **ALL** rows in that table despite what the `orderNumber` says.

[Documentation on MySQL's `GROUP BY` handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

So the most *reliable* version of your query and the only version which would work outside of MySQL, where you can actually predict the results would be:

```
SELECT 
    T1.orderNumber,
    status,
    SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) total
FROM
    orders AS T1
        INNER JOIN
    orderdetails AS T2 ON T1.orderNumber = T2.orderNumber
GROUP BY 
  orderNumber,
  status /* added */
;
```

Note that the tutorial omitted `status` from the `GROUP BY` even though it is in `SELECT`. That would be an error in most other RDBMS.

MySQL's default handling of this misfeature has changed with recent versions. Prior to 5.7, [the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode was disabled by default, arguably causing a lot of developers to grow dependent on the grouping behavior. In recent versions, `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is *enabled* by default and prevents queries with a missing or incomplete `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Just to observe that the link references the 5.7 documentation, which is correct as far as the argument being made above, but that argument slightly disregards the current version.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you - link pointed to 8 and bit added about contemporary defaults

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much, Michael! You invested tremendous amount of effort in answering my question, I now start seeing things clearer, thank you!

Comment: @SergejFomin Glad to help, good luck to you.